# wordpress table prefix wp_ is not being used

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an wordpress setup into /blog folder under my site directory.

I have a .inc file for fetching the latest blog posts from wordpress to show into my site's homepage.

But when i include that .inc file in my site's homepage via php include, i get redirected to login page.

After a bit of debugging i found this query into the function is_blog_installed()

```
"SELECT option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'"
```

which simply gives me this when i echo this -

```
SELECT option_value FROM options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'
```

thats is the options table name is "options", not "wp_options", which means the table_prefix set in wp-config.php file is not being used.

I don't know why this is happening. So, please help!

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: When you say my site's home page, is it the blog home page or is it a different home?

Comment: This is different home. the site's homepage, the entire blog is installed in /blogs folders.

Comment: Check $wpdb->prefix variable and try to use wp-load.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that it is because the database connectivity issue between my site and that of the wordpress. I resolved this by capturing the wordpress content using output buffering before any of my sites database connection is being made and using the captured wordpress html markup later when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the wordpress environment into your .inc-file. 
try

```
include 'blog/wp-load.php'; // Adjust to your environment
```

This is probably not the best way to do this. Perhaps you can run the script as a cronjob (using WordPress built-in scheduling) to generate a textfile to include on the home page instead?

Comment: I m using this -- define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); //we don't need the theme
 require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php'); //this loads the API

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a plugin.  I had to do:

```
$mailsign_dir = 
    substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],$ds));
$plugins_dir = 
    substr($mailsign_dir, 0, strrpos($mailsign_dir,$ds));
$wp_content_dir = 
    substr($plugins_dir, 0, strrpos($plugins_dir,$ds));
$wordpress_dir = 
    substr($wp_content_dir, 0, strrpos($wp_content_dir,$ds));
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$wordpress_dir);
require_once('wp-load.php');
```

and after doing this, I was able to use :

```
function myMethod(){
  global $wpdb;
  // use $wpdb->options here
}
```

to access all of the database object properties in my method